# How to install a NavigationController as the root view in a tab bar?

Tags: iphone, ios, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

How to install a NavigationController as the root view in a tab bar view?

In my applicaton:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: method I created a tab bar interface, setting the rootViewController of the window as the tabBarController.

Now, in one of my tab bar views, I want to add a navigation bar at the top. How can I accomplish this?

Should I subclass navigationcontroller?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you're doing it in code, not IB, so here's what you can do.

```
// First create your RootViewController:
UIViewController *rootViewController = [[UIViewController alloc] init];
// Then add the rootViewController to a UINavigationController
UINavigationController *navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:rootViewController];
// Now your RootViewController is a UINavigationController
// Add it to your UITabBarController
[tabBarController.viewControllers addObject:navigationController];
// You can now get rid of the RootViewController and UINavigationController
[rootViewController release];
[navigationController release];
```

Comment: thanks! I am trying to do it programmatically vs IB. Thank you very much, this helps immensely

Comment: Actually, so now how do I make the navigationCOntroller show up when the tab is selected?

Comment: That should come automatically. The tabBarController should take care of this for you.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this in the Interface Builder. Replace the view controller inside the tab bar controller with a navigation controller. Then set the class and Nib name of the view controller (inside the navigation controller) to your root class.

Answer (score 0):

You have to first create a UITabbarController application, then go to MainWindow.xib file. By default two tab view will be created.

Check the attribute property of the tab bar and change the view to RootViewController. You will have to set the class name and xib file name to RootViewController.